# What's the best practice of creating models and getting the information using the Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I'd like to know what is the best way of creating models using the Laravel framework? As far as I know, the model is used for the connection to the DB table and then, you can do whatever you want with its data.

Creating a new model per DB table (as stated [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139438/models-per-database-table)) isn't good and models should be created per business object. Not sure what it means. I'd like to access the same table and get some information from it using the Eloquent, so similar to this:

```
<?php

// Get the model class
use App\Post;

// Grab some data from the posts table
$posts = Post::all();
```

But it requires having a model. Using the `select` method, e.g.:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->select('title, body')->get();
```

Doesn't require having a model so I don't quite understand what's the point of models? I couldn't find enough information inside the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent.

Comment: "_the model is used for the connection to the DB table_" Note that there are models without DB connection/table.

Comment: The point is it's a class you can use like other classes but is also backed by a database row. If you're writing code using object oriented programming then it's more useful to have a class representing the actual object you have instead of dumping everything in arrays or standard objects.

Comment: So you would recommend creating a new model every time I try to do something with the database? That's a lot of models :O

Comment: No, you create a model for each entity in your database not for every thing in your database. For example: `users` is an entity, `roles` is an entity but `user_roles` is not an entity but a relationship. If you think that's too many models then just make models of things that would be useful to be models .

Comment: So, in simple terms, one model per database table (entity)?

Comment: Yes, models represent entities in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a full explanation of your question:

Using method:

```
<?php

// Get the model class
use App\Post;

// Grab some data from the posts table
$posts = Post::all();
```

will be the same as running a query like:

```
<?php 
$posts = DB::table('posts')->select('*')->get();
```

but the biggest difference is that the first returns an Eloquent object, while the later returns a normal object. The first model requires a model, which extends eloquent, the later method is using the DB class, which does not extend eloquent. So when you want to use Eloquent you would have to use models.

> Creating a new model per DB table (as stated here) isn't good and models should be created per business object. Not sure what it means.

Entities are things like Users, Posts, Comments, messages, but not relation tables such as user_has_posts or user_has_messages. Not entirely sure how else to explain it, but i'm sure you will get the idea.

Also keep in mind, models are supposed to only contain database logics, I've seen it plenty of times where people use models to filter arrays but this should not belong to models.

Comment: Very nice explanation! Thanks :)